# SignalR does not drop WebSocket connections (Perf: "Connections Current WebSockets")

Tags: azure, signalr

Seeing some issues with WebSocket connections not being dispose/closed on a cluster of 3x Windows Server 2012 R2.

Eventually the servers won't allow any more connections and starts failing on serverSentEvents as well.

When looking at the SignalR Performance Counters, there appears that WebSocket counter does not drop as "Connections Current" drops.

Right now I'm seeing this on two of the three servers, not long since the servers was restarted so numbers are not that high:

```
Server #1:
Connections Current: 8
Connections Current WebSockets: 131
Connections Disconnected: 202

Server #2:
Connections Current: 6
Connections Current WebSockets: 5
Connections Current ServerSentEvents: 1

Server #3:
Connections Current: 3
Connections Current WebSockets: 101
Connections Disconnected: 101
```

Right now there is a stable amount of (few) users, so the numbers don't grow much, but when traffic increases it does eventually stop accepting WebSocket connections.

SignalR (v2.2.1) is hosted using OWIN and the process is running on Azure Service Fabric.

Attempted to search for troubleshooting and others with same problem, but not found any solution or potential cause of the problem. From what I can understand from the perf count numbers, it appears that disconnect events are triggered and registered properly, but the actual connections are kept.

**Edit #1 (2017-03-24):**

Have run some monitoring with TCPView from Sysinternals, it does report the exact same WebSockets connections as the Current Connections, so the problem is probably not exhaustion of system resources.

Also as I mentioned, we are getting disconnected events in the perf counters, yet the number of "Connections Current WebSockets" is a lot higher than the actual connections. It does at times drop one or two, as users connect or disconnect, so it's not simply growing and growing, but it does not drop by much, and right now the current websockets connections number is the same as maximum number, status today:

```
Server #1:
Current: 9
WebSockets: 151

Server #2:
Current: 6
WebSockets: 9

Server #3:
Current: 4
WebSockets: 120
```

**Edit #2 (2017-03-24):**

Upgraded Azure Service Fabric from 5.4.145 to 5.4.164 to 5.5.216, the last update restarted all the VMs. So far after a few hours of running, it appears that "Connections Current" and "Connections Current WebSockets" reports the exact same numbers for all 3 VMs. There was at least one WCF socket leak bug fix in the latest release.

I'll update this post over the weekend, after we got some more use and users.

**Edit #3 (2017-03-28):**

After deployment of a cluster project upgrade to the Service Fabric VMs, the "Connections Current WebSockets" again reports higher than "Connections Current" number.

```
Server #1:
Connections Current: 8
Connections Current WebSockets: 31
```

The two others reports same numbers for both metrics.

**Edit #4 (2017-04-18)**

Removed Redis as backplane for SignalR, and changed the code to call each individual instance of SignalR instead of relying on the Backplane-logic. This seems to remove the stability issues we had, but I'm still seeing a difference in active connections and web socket connections. From one server now, I'm seeing 6 current connections, but web socket current returns 8.

Might attempt to re-introduce Redis when SignalR 2.2.2 is released, from the preview: "A bunch of work making Redis Scaleout more reliable".

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/04/13/announcing-signalr-2-2-2-preview-1/

Comment: Do you see any reconnects? What client do you use - C#? JavaScript?